# Javascript: Detect if an image that has been set as SRC has finished loading?

Tags: jquery

I have an image:

```
<img src="http://localhost/image1.jpg" id="myImage" />
```

Then I have javascript:

```
function event() {
   $("#myImage").attr("src", "http://localhost/image2.jpg");
}
```

I want to show the words "loading" while the image is NOT FINISHED loading. How can I detect when image2.jpg has finished loading so I can change the image to the desired image. I was thinking something like:

```
function event() {
   $("#myImage").hide();
   $("#loadingBlock").show();
   if ( hasLoaded("http://localhost/image2.jpg") ) {
     $("#myImage").attr("src", "http://localhost/image2.jpg");
     $("#loadingBlock").hide();
     $("#myImage").show();
   }
}
```

How would the "hasLoaded" function work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myImage")
        .load(function() { console.log("image loaded correctly");
         //your code to show image..
        })
        .error(function() { console.log("error loading image"); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind an handler on the `load` event :

```
$("#loadingBlock").show();
$("#myImage")
   .hide()
   .load(function() { 
      $("#loadingBlock").hide();
      $(this).show();
   })
   .prop("src", "http://localhost/image2.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use complete event of load, read more over [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
$("#myImage").load("http://localhost/image2.jpg", function(){
   alert("loaded");
});
```